# Suggestion what to use for websocket server yaws or mochiweb or plane Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am very new to Erlang and I need to create websocket server connected with postgre.
I googled and found `yaws` and `mochiweb` and examples in book `Programming Erlang by Joe Armstrong`.
Can anyone with more experience direct for better solution what to use ?
Server is simple and should answer on maybe 15 different `JSON` messages

Comment: I think you can read this article:http://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/HEAD/guide/ws_handlers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

websockets are not super-straightforward to implement.

I've used [Cowboy](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy) on several occasions and find it easy, fast and simple to embed in my applications.